# How should I save user profile data locally and securely in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, security

I am creating a VB.NET application for a Calculus class as a little side-project. It requires user profiles that are saved locally in the program's main files. I am using 2 separate classes to access the user profiles right now.

The first class is called *Config* and it is used to manipulate the basic config file which contains lesson document paths, settings, and user profile names.

The second class is called *User* and it is used to load up user profiles from a profile directory where user data is saved in separate text files.

The *Config* class retrieves the user names, and user profile text file paths. This text file path is then handed off to a User object that can then load up and interpret the file.

Sorry, if that was an overly informative bit, but I thought it would help explain things.

My question is how should I format the config file and user files so they are secure enough that someone can not easily retrieve or manipulate data?

Here is a sample of how I am reading the text files:

```
Dim userList() As String = {Nothing}
If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(configPath + "config.cfg") Then
    Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(configPath + "config.cfg")
        MyReader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        MyReader.Delimiters = New String() {"="}
        Dim currentRow As String()
            'Loop through all of the fields in the file.' 
            'If any lines are corrupt, report an error and continue parsing.' 
        While Not MyReader.EndOfData
            Try
                currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
                    'interpret data tokens delimited by "=" and new line character here'
            Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & " is invalid.  Skipping")
            End Try
        End While
    End Using
End If
```

The problem isn't reading the text file, I am just not sure how to make it secure. I was thinking about first parsing the entire file to translate it from 'encrypted' to text, and then save it as a temporary file which I would pass off to the above code, then delete the file immediately afterward. As for 'encrypting' (is that the right word for this?) the file, I could maybe bit-shift each character using a key that I would save at the beginning of the file.

I am more interested in saving the file securely then worrying how much of an over-kill it might be. This is more of practice I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... .NET includes A LOT of security and encryption classes.
I would begin your search by looking in the System.Security.Cryptography namespace.

If you need help implementing a specific method from within the options there, let us know.

As a side note, you should be able to handle all of your file access from the System.IO namespace.  Try to stay away from the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace as a lot of the stuff in there is no longer best practice.

-edit: Typo.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good example on how to encrypt/decrypt files using vb.net on codeproject.com
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/EncryptFile.aspx

Comment: wow thanks for posting that article! I just read it... I think I am gonna just try my own type of 'fast' encryption. But the techniques he used were very informative. Thanks